npm: how to add fallback registry that is not registry.npmjs.org
I have a project where I need to configure a couple of scoped registries for specific dependencies, and a fallback one that is not registry.npmjs.org.
My .npmrc definitions for the two scoped registries looks something like this:
//[registry domain and path for scope1]:_authToken=[the token]
@scope1:registry=[registry domain and path for scope1]
//[registry domain and path for scope2]:_authToken=[the token]
@scope2:registry=[registry domain and path for scope1]

... and this works just swell - I can see the dependencies resolved to the right registries respectively for the scoped dependencies.
However, I am trying to specify the registry for all other dependencies aside from "scope1" and "scope2", and I want it to point to yet another private registry that is not registry.npmjs.org.
This is where my attempts so far have failed.
I got the 3rd entry in the .npmrc file to either look like:
//[registry domain and path for no scope]:_authToken=[the token]

... or like:
//[registry domain and path for empty scope]:_authToken=[the token]
@:registry=[registry domain and path for empty scope]

Regardless of whether a choose an "empty" scope syntax or simply no scope for the "fallback" registry, I can still see the "resolved" entries being added to the yarn.lock file as emanating from registry.npmjs.org - which is precisely what I want to avoid.
Conversely, the entries with specific, non-empty scope are indeed being resolved to the right registries.
My testing methodology for this issue consists in the following steps:

delete the node_modules directory
make any adjustments to the .npmrc file via npm login --scope... --registry...
remove any "resolved" line from the yarn.lock file (e.g. via sed)
run npm install

The "closest" Q&A I found was this one, but it doesn't help my case since the fallback in that question has to be registry.npmjs.org - which is precisely what I don't want.
Note that I have verified my private fallback registry does indeed serve the dependencies I need.
Given the number of dependencies, I've only tested a few of them, but even for those "sure" entries, yarn.lock shows "resolved" as the registry.npmjs.org regardless, meaning my fallback syntax somehow doesn't work - regardless if I use no scope or an empty scope.
TL;DR
Is there a way to set up the npm registries with a fallback registry that isn't the publicly available registry.npmjs.org?
Edit
Just realized I mention the yarn lock a few times over the question as running npm install modifies the file in my case, but this is just added noise. In order to verify where the dependencies are fetched I can just as well look at the package-lock.json file and replicate the issue exactly in the same way.
